# Android how to format decimal digits to two

Tags: android, decimalformat

I have to the this number 0.6044610142707825 and i want to format this into 600.
I tried the following

```
new DecimalFormat("###.#")
    .format(temp)
```

This did return 0.6.
Please help me to find the right format for doing this.

Comment: You want to have 0.600 or 600?

Comment: Opiatefuchs I want 600

Comment: Well if that returned 0.6, then just multiply it by 1000....

Comment: just be clear what you want... 600 or 0.600

Comment: And what should be in case of 234.567?? 234 or 567??

Comment: @PankajKumar I have condition to check if it is greater than one(>1) so here 234

Comment: Ohk Then Multiply it by 1000 and then use following ....int value = valueBigDecimal.intValue();

Comment: @rsay3 Thanks, thats a nice fix but i would like to know the format or the right way for doing this.

Comment: Thanks all i multiplied the input by 1000 and it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **[decimalformat](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html)**

```
// Fetch only the first rounded off digit after decimal.
String abc = new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(0.604461014);
// Converting to integer and multiply 1000
int myFinalNo =  (int) ( Double.parseDouble(abc) * 1000);
// Returns output 600
```

---

**Note:**

```
String abc = new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(0.674461014);
int myFinalNo =  (int) ( Double.parseDouble(abc) * 1000);
// Returns output 700
```

If you **DO NOT WANT ROUNDING**, then use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String abc = df.format(0.684461014);
int myFinalNo = (int) ( Double.parseDouble(abc) * 1000);
System.out.println ("abc="+abc + "** myFinalNo="+myFinalNo);
```

Comment: @IllegalArgument: Try now. Previous was uncompiled version.

Answer (score 1):

this could solve your problem...

```
temp = 0.6044610142707825;

new DecimalFormat("###")
    .format(temp*1000); //converts to 604.4610142707825 and then to 604;
```

Comment: This is what i did as my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`String.format("%.2f", d)`, your decimal will be rounded automatically. by 2 digit after dot operator 
where d is your value

Comment: give ur inpout value and your output value which u want

Comment: i noted everything in my question  0.6044610142707825-input
600-output

Comment: then mutiply to input by 1000 its easy n simple

Comment: first do roundup by String.format("%.3f", d) and then multiply it by 1000 you will get your output

Comment: Android is everything for me Thanks i multiplied the input by 1000 and it worked..

Comment: if this post is useful then accept it as your answer if it worked then only :)